# stack operations using switch case

Tags: c, compiler-errors, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define max 20
int stk[max];
int top=-1;
void push(int);
int pop();
void peep();
void display();
int isFull();
int isEmpty();

int main()
{
    int ch,item;
    do
    {
        printf("....Stack Operations....\n");
        printf("Press 1 for Push\n");
        printf("Press 2 for pop\n");
        printf("Press 3 for peep\n");
        printf("Press 4 for display\n");
        
        printf("Enter your choice \n");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1:
                    printf("Enter the item :- \n");
                    scanf("%d",&item);
                    push(item);
                    break;
            case 2:
                    int k=pop();
                    printf("The poped element is %d\n",k);
                    break;
            case 3:
                    peep();
                    break;
            case 4:
                    display();
                    break;
            default:
                    printf("Invalid Choice\n");
        }
    }while(ch>=1 && ch<=5);
    
    void push(int item)
    {
        if(isFull())
        printf("Stack Overflow\n");
        else
        {
            top=top+1;
            stk[top]=item;
        }
    }
    int pop()
    {
        int s;
        if(isEmpty())
        printf("Stack Underflow\n");
        else
        {
            s=stk[top];
            top=top-1;
        }
        return s;
    }
    void peep()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        printf("Stack Underflow\n");
        else
        {
            printf("Topmost Element of the stack is %d",stk[top]);
        }
    }
    void display()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        printf("Stack Underflow\n");
        else
        {
            for(int i=top;i>=0;i--)
            printf("%d ",stk[i]);
        }
    }
    int isFull()
    {
        if(top==max-1)
        return 1;
        else
        return 0;
    }
    int isEmpty()
    {
        if(top==-1)
        return 1;
        else
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I wanted the program to run for all stack operations but I am getting this type of specific error:-

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccHJ1ZkB.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xf7): undefined reference to `push'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x103): undefined reference to `pop'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x12b): undefined reference to `peep'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x137): undefined reference to `display'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You have `push()` and so on defined within `main() { ... }` - you need to close that before those definitions.

Comment: Standard C does not allow nested functions.  GCC does (and I wish it didn't).  You have created nested functions — unnest them.  They would have to be defined before they are used if you keep them as nested functions.  As it stands, they're are merely unused.  You should be compiling with more warning flags: `gcc -Werror -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu18 -pedantic` would probably be a good starting point (maybe add `-pedantic-errors`).  If your compiler doesn't support C18, now would be a good time to upgrade.  C23 will be out later this year (early next year).

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not standard C to define functions within another function (`main()`) aka "nested function".
2. `pop()` returns an undefined value if the stack is empty.  I changed it to return `-1` but really you want to add the ability to tell caller of errors like this.
3. You need a block `{}` when introducing variables in a switch statement.
4. (not fixed) Avoid global variables and instead pass values to the functions that need them (functional style).  Usually, you then group related data (`stk` and `top`) into a `struct`.
5. (not fixed) By convention constants, like `max`, should be upper case.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define max 20
int stk[max];
int top=-1;

int isFull() {
    return top==max-1;
}

int isEmpty() {
    return top==-1;
}

void push(int item) {
    if(isFull()) {
        printf("Stack Overflow\n");
        return;
    }
    stk[top++]=item;
}

int pop() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        printf("Stack Underflow\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return stk[top--];
}

void peep() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        printf("Stack Underflow\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("Topmost Element of the stack is %d",stk[top]);
}

void display() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        printf("Stack Underflow\n");
        return;
    }
    for(int i=top; i>=0; i--)
        printf("%d ", stk[i]);
}

int main() {
    int ch;
    do {
        printf(
            "....Stack Operations....\n"
            "Press 1 for Push\n"
            "Press 2 for pop\n"
            "Press 3 for peep\n"
            "Press 4 for display\n"
            "Enter your choice \n"
        );
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        switch(ch) {
            case 1: {
                printf("Enter the item :- \n");
                int item;
                scanf("%d", &item);
                push(item);
                break;
            }
            case 2:
                printf("The popped element is %d\n", pop());
                break;
            case 3:
                peep();
                break;
            case 4:
                display();
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid Choice\n");
        }
    } while(ch>=1 && ch<=5);
}
```

Comment: If that answered your question please click on the check mark next to it so we know you are all set.